# How to make 3 separate columns on page?

Tags: html, css

This is what I'm trying to achieve:
[image]

[So far, this is the code I have.](http://jsfiddle.net/sAw5B/1/)

The columns work like they should. The problem is that whatever I place after the columns in my HTML is actually behind the columns on the page, not beneath them like I want.

Would it be a problem with the css that I'm using for the "test-box" div?

```
.test-box{
    background:red;
    width:100%;
    height:300px;
}
```

Is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: Works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/sAw5B/1/show/  The "HTML" window in jsFiddle is very small, so your HTML didn't quite fit.

Comment: Look at how other people acheive this. For example, take a look at [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/sAw5B/8/ change width for column div, check css

Answer (score 5):

```
.test-box{
background:red;
width:100%;
height:300px;
clear:both;
}
```

clear: both will clear your other div from being affected by the floats, therefore placing it after

Comment: That was so much easier than I was making it out to be. Thank you for the help!

Comment: no problem, try to remember it! clear and floats together can do magic

Answer (score 1):

It can be done by adding a clear: both; to the CSS of the test-box:

```
.test-box{
    clear: both;
    background:red;
    width:100%;
    height:300px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `clear: both;` or `float: left;` (if the 3 column divs take up the entire width.

Answer (score 0):

you need to add

`.test-box{clear:both;}`

The [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sAw5B/2/)

Answer (score 0):

adding more always keep this at the end of a css

```
.clearfix {
  clear:both;
}
```

and call it

`<div class="test-box clearfix">`

Answer (score 0):

in this class

```
.three-columns div{
    ... 
    display:table-cell;

}
```

just remove the float:left and add display:table-cell

Answer (score 0):

I personally wouldn't set the height in px unless you are 100% sure that the text will never change. there are different ways to achieve this, one way would be:

1) give a single class to each box ".box" for example

```
.box{
  width:33.33%;
  margin:20px 0 0 20px;
  float:left;
}
```

also remember to clear:both what comes after these boxes.

This would be a responsive solution, although you can use a px based solution. It really depends on what the requirements are.